# Down and . X times?

Tags: repeated-commands

Say I perform a combination of keys and now they are registered in `.`

Now I want to go down X lines and run `.` on each one.

For example say I have:

```
{colorComponentId: 0, value: (value.warmWhite * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 1, value: (value.coldWhite * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 2, value: (value.red * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 3, value: (value.green * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 4, value: (value.blue * 255)}
```

I then run `d/}` just after `value:` resulting in:

```
{colorComponentId: 0, value:},
{colorComponentId: 1, value: (value.coldWhite * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 2, value: (value.red * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 3, value: (value.green * 255)},
{colorComponentId: 4, value: (value.blue * 255)}
```

I then found myself pressing `down+.` 4 more times.

```
{colorComponentId: 0, value:},
{colorComponentId: 1, value:},
{colorComponentId: 2, value:},
{colorComponentId: 3, value:},
{colorComponentId: 4, value:}
```

Is there are a way to say something like "do `.` down X times"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a macro, though it does require a (small) bit of planning ahead:

```
qqdt}jq4@q
```

will work, assuming your cursor is starting on the first line on the space after `value:`. Here's an explanation:

```
q
Start recording a macro...
 q
...in register `q`...
  dt}j
...delete until the next `}` and then go down one line...
      q
...finish recording the macro...
       4@q
...replay the macro in register `q` 4 times.
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a macro:

Juste before the deletion do:

```
qqdf)jq
```

Which means:

- `qq` start to record a macro in the register `q`
- `df)` your deletion
- `j` go down one line
- `q` stop recording the macro

Then you can press several time `@q` to replay the macro of the `q` register or simply `4@q` to replay it 4 times.

---

Or you could go with a substitution:

Visually select the lines you want to modify and then:

```
:'<,'>s/(.*)//
```

Which means:

- `'<,'>` between the selected line
- `s/` substitute
- `(.*)` anything between the parenthesys
- `//` replace it by nothing

---

See:

- [`:h complex-repeat`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#complex%2drepeat)
- [`:h :s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as)